# Crystal Report Error When entering values

Tags: crystal-reports

I am having script error while running a report in crystal report 11. It keeps popping up after tying 1 value. Disabling internet explore options aint helping.

I am having script error while running a report in crystal report 11. It keeps popping up after tying 1 value. Disabling internet explore options aint helping.